# Filtering data for first time not working with react-query

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query, react-data-table-component

I have a basic ReactJS component that uses `react-query ("@tanstack/react-query": "^4.24.6")` and `"react-data-table-component": "^7.5.3"`. The data gets loaded, I display it in a table. Standard stuff, works fine.

I had a search component as described [here](https://react-data-table-component.netlify.app/?path=/docs/examples-filtering--filtering), which was working fine. During site UI redesign, I externalized the search box so it no longer sits within the data table component.

To let users search from the search box, I am doing what seems to be a simple 4-step process:

1. Loading data remains the same:

```
const {data, isLoading} = useQuery(["whatever"], () => {
        return getDataFromBackend();
    }, {
        refetchInterval: 10000
    });
```

2. I defined a new state variable, as follows:

```
const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState(data);
```

3. I defined an onSearch function to handle changes to search box, and changed filteredData based on the search text:

```
    const onSearch = (searchText) => {
        if (!searchText || searchText.length === 0) {
            setFilteredData(data);
            return;
        }
        // Filter data based on search text
        const filteredData = rawFilesList.filter(item => {
            return (
                // Whatever logic needed to filter
            )
        });
        setFilteredData(filteredData);
    }
```

4. And finally, I pass filteredData to the table:

```
<DataTable
    data={filteredData}
/>
```

This works as expected, EXCEPT when the react-query initial value is undefined (on first load or if I remove the query value using the dev tool). After query loads data, the "data" field gets updated, but it does not trigger the table to be reloaded. As soon as I type something into the search field, normal services are restored, but it is not clear to me why the filteredData variable does not get loaded correctly.

I tried adding an explicit setFilteredData, but that also did not help:

```
    if (isLoading) {
        return <>
            <div>Loading..</div>
        </>
    }

    setFilteredData(data);
```

I made the following change to step #1 above, and it *seems* to work, but I am not sure if this breaks the behavior of isLoading and other flags:

```
const {data, isLoading} = useQuery(["whatever"], async () => {
        const x = await getDataFromBackend();
        setFilteredData(x);
        return x;
    }, {
        refetchInterval: 10000
    });
```

Any help on getting the first load to work as expected would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because of how `useState` works:

```
const { data } = useQuery(...)
const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState(data);
```

`data` will be `undefined` on the first render, so you pass `undefined` to `useState`. When data then comes in later, `useState` has already been initialized, so the changing value will be ignored.

What you can do is either:

- break the things up into multiple components

Have one component that calls `useQuery`, render loading & error states, then pass it as `initialFilteredData` to another component (once data exists). There, you can put it into `useState`, because the component mounts later.

An even better approach is:

- don't store server state in `useState`, only store what the user has changed.

In your case, this could be as simple as:

```
const { data } = useQuery(...)
const [userData, setUserData] = useState();

const filteredData = userData ?? data
```

Note how we pass nothing to `useState`, so it will initialize with `undefined`, and then, we'll *derive* `filteredData` from that or the server value. This deriving happens on every render, so if `data` from `useQuery` changes, `filteredData` will pick it up (unless you already have something in your local state).

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! I used the second approach.

Answer (score 0):

I know you already had your solution but I just want to share my trick.

What I did is adding

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (data)
      setFilteredData(data)
  }, [data])
```

So it ensure that anytime I receive new `data` from the `useQuery()`, it always trigger my setState function.

Hope this can help you in any similar situations in the future.